# Reading a custom class property in VBA not working

Tags: excel, vba, class, properties

I have set up the test class with a Get and Let but when assigned values they are not returned.

```
'Set up test class

Private lTargetName As String

Public Property Get TargetName() As String
TargetName = ITargetName
End Property

Public Property Let TargetName(value As String)
lTargetName = value
End Property

Sub test()
Dim sharedColumn As TestClass
Set sharedColumn = TestClass

sharedColumn.TargetName = "test"
Debug.Print sharedColumn.TargetName ' returns blank
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you creating the instance? I see no `New` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.  The first is with the class itself.  Your Property Get is assigning iTargetName instead of lTargetName.  Also, in your Sub Test, you are not New-ing up the TestClass.  Make these 2 changes and you'll be good to go.

One recommendation:  place Option Explicit at the top of your source files to help catch these errors.

Comment: Fantastic Brian thank you -  my local variables were wrong  :) now it works